# Unable to disable php8.0

Tags: php, ubuntu-18.04

By accident I installed PHP8.0.14. I have also PHP7.4. Now when trying to disable php8.0 using
 `a2dismod php8.0` it says `ERROR: Module php8.0 does not exist!`,
but `php -v` says `PHP 8.0.14 (cli) (built: Dec 20 2021 21:22:38) ( NTS )`

[image]

Comment: Just uninstall it (via apt) if you don't want it

Comment: Remember `php -v` runs the PHP CLI. There is no reason to believe that the version of PHP used by Apache is the same version.

Comment: But you can check using `<?php phpinfo() ?>`